# Dictionary prints the same value names

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with 3 keys and multiple values for each key.

```
import os
import glob
import re 
import itertools 
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict 

path = 'C://Users/123/Desktop/files'

list_inst = []

main_inst = [' INST1', ' INST2', ' INST3']
common_inst = []
dictionary = defaultdict(list)

regex = re.compile('(?i)inst(\s+\w+)')
inst_list = []
files_name = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        with open(os.path.join(path,filename),"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                match=(re.findall(regex,line))
                if match: 
                    inst_list=inst_list + match 
                    #print(inst_list)
                    file_list = []
                    file_ex = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
                    file_list.append(file_ex)
                    for m in main_inst:
                        if m in inst_list:
                            dictionary[m]=file_list

    inst_list=[]
print(dictionary)
```

The output comes out as:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {' INST1': ['XYZ', 'XYZ'], ' INST2': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']})
```

I want the output to be:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {' INST1': ['XYZ', 'MNO'], ' INST2': ['ABC', 'DJS', 'WEF', 'VSD', 'GDS',....]})
```

By changing the location of print, it does not help. I am assuming something is wrong with the way in which the dictionary is being created here. I am very new to all these concepts and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `main_inst` isn't defined.

Comment: use `print()` in different places to see values in variables - it can help to see where is problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have defined it above. Everything works perfectly. Just the printing is an issue.

Comment: @furas I did. It either prints just the final value. Or list of multiple items with the same name as the final value.

Comment: use `print()` between other lines - not only at the end. And check values in different variables. OR learn how to use debuger. Problem is code which generates dictionary, not printing. We don't have your data and we can't run you code, so you have to tes all elements on your own.

Comment: you should create minimal working code which we could run and test.

Comment: Hi @furas I edited the code to paste the entire code. I have a folder called file with all the text files that are in interest. Thanks.

Comment: you should add example data from file so we could test it. Besides, what if problem is not code but data in files?

Comment: @furas It works perfectly until the regex matching so the files dont have any problem. There is some issue with the placement of appending file names to the dictionary. I am even able to print inst_list exactly the way I want.
The files are nothing but a bunch of instructions like : INST 20, INST 28.
I need to capture the files that contain INST 1, INST 2 and INST 3 and make a dictionary in order to export this data to an excel sheet.

Comment: in last part of code I see two problems: (1) you have too many useless lists, and (2) you have to use `.append()` instead of `= ` when you add to `dictionary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reductions

```
import os
import re 
from collections import defaultdict 

path = 'C://Users/123/Desktop/files'
#path = '.'

main_inst = [' INST1', ' INST2', ' INST3']
main_inst_set = set(main_inst)
dictionary = defaultdict(list)

regex = re.compile('(?i)inst(\s+\w+)')
#regex = re.compile(r'(?i)inst\s*( INST[123])\b')

for filename in sorted(os.listdir(path)):  # filenames in alphabetical order
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = re.findall(regex, line)
                match = set(match) & main_inst_set
                #print(match, line.strip())
                if match: 
                    file_ex = filename[:-4] # because `.txt` has 4 chars
                    for m in match:
                         dictionary[m].append(file_ex)
                    #file_ex = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
                    #for m in match:
                    #    if m in main_inst:
                    #        dictionary[m].append(file_ex)

print(dictionary)
print('---')
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print(key, value)
```

ABC.txt

```
inst INST1
inst INST2
inst INST3
inst INST15
```

MNO.txt

```
inst INST1
inst INST3
```

XYZ.txt

```
inst INST2
inst INST3
inst INST4
```

Result

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {' INST1': ['ABC', 'MNO'], ' INST2': ['ABC', 'XYZ'], ' INST3': ['ABC', 'MNO', 'XYZ']})
---
 INST1 ['ABC', 'MNO']
 INST2 ['ABC', 'XYZ']
 INST3 ['ABC', 'MNO', 'XYZ']
```